# Route (path) working in console but not in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

The following code in my view/helper errors out with an invalid object, but when I run the same code in the console it seems to work. I appreciate any help that you can provide.

**This does not work --**

```
2.2.1 :032 > purchase_orders.map do |purchase_order|
2.2.1 :033 >      [ERB::Util.h(purchase_order.name),
2.2.1 :034 >       ERB::Util.h(purchase_order.descr),
2.2.1 :035 >       link_to("Copy PO", purchase_order_copy_path(purchase_order))]
2.2.1 :036?>   end

NoMethodError: undefined method `purchase_order_copy_path' for main:Object
    from (irb):36:in `block in irb_binding'
    from /home/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:13:in `map'
    from /home/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:13:in `map'
    from (irb):32
    from /home/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /home/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

**This one works in the console --**

```
2.2.1 :037 > app.purchase_order_copy_path(purchase_orders.first)
 => "/purchase_orders/1/copy"
```

Comment: So what is your question exactly? If it is 'why does it work in the one example and not in the other', my guess is that you're accessing the named route on your 'app' object in the example that works. You app object probably being an instance of ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.

Comment: are you sure that you are calling `purchase_order_copy_path` from view?

Comment: @LongNguyen - I am NOT using inside a view, but at app/datatables/purchase_order_datatable.rb. My view calls this class over ajax which is supposed to return a json object that DataTable then renders.

I included ActionDispatch::Routing inside my class file and it does not seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Rob Cameron](http://ridingtheclutch.com/post/1299774075/using-rails-3-route-helpers-outside-of-a), all I had to do was Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.purchase_order_copy_path in my datatable class